# StorageException has occurred. Object does not exist at location -> when deleting a folder/path in firebase storage

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I store the user photos in firebase storage folder/path named with its uid.
Deleting the files won't do a problem but when I try to **delete the folder/path** containing it, I got this exception and other exceptions also, **though the folder is deleted**:

> E/StorageException(16352): StorageException has occurred. Object does not exist at location.

this is a code snippet of the delete method:

```
// Delete Profile Photo
  try {
    final profilePhotoRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('images/${user.uid}');
    // delete every file within the path
    profilePhotoRef.listAll().then((value) {
      for (var element in value.items) {
        FirebaseStorage.instance.ref(element.fullPath).delete();
      }
    });
    // Now delete the containing folder/path
    profilePhotoRef.delete();   // --> here is the problem
  } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
    print("Failed with error '${e.code}': ${e.message}");
  }
```

and this is list of the exceptions I got:

> W/NetworkRequest(16352): No App Check token for request.
> E/StorageException(16352): StorageException has occurred.
> E/StorageException(16352): Object does not exist at location.
> E/StorageException(16352):  Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404
> E/StorageException(16352): {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found."  }}
> E/StorageException(16352): java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found."  }}
> E/StorageException(16352):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseResponse(NetworkRequest.java:445)
> E/StorageException(16352):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseErrorResponse(NetworkRequest.java:462)
> E/StorageException(16352):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.processResponseStream(NetworkRequest.java:453)
> E/StorageException(16352):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(NetworkRequest.java:272)
> E/StorageException(16352):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(NetworkRequest.java:289)
> E/StorageException(16352):  at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(ExponentialBackoffSender.java:76)
> E/StorageException(16352):  at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(ExponentialBackoffSender.java:68)
> E/StorageException(16352):  at com.google.firebase.storage.DeleteStorageTask.run(DeleteStorageTask.java:59)
> E/StorageException(16352):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
> E/StorageException(16352):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
> E/StorageException(16352):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
> E/flutter (16352): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_storage/object-not-found] No object exists at the desired reference.
> E/flutter (16352): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:653:7)
> E/flutter (16352): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:315:18)
> E/flutter (16352): 
> E/flutter (16352): #2      MethodChannelReference.delete (package:firebase_storage_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_reference.dart:26:7)
> E/flutter (16352): 
> E/flutter (16352):
> D/FirebaseAuth(16352): Notifying id token listeners about a sign-out event.
> D/FirebaseAuth(16352): Notifying auth state listeners about a sign-out event.
> Reloaded 1 of 1803 libraries in 3,669ms (compile: 1488 ms, reload: 1010 ms, reassemble: 302 ms).
> W/example.khedme(16352): Reducing the number of considered missed Gc histogram windows from 153 to 100

Thank you in advance, it took me a lot of time and I didn't find a solution.

Comment: I would presume that when you delete the last file in the folder, Firestore is deleting the folder automatically. You can test that by putting a break point on the folder delete line and examining the Firestore location via the console. If true, then you don't need the delete folder line.

Comment: Really weird, I tried this approach before but it left the "folder" empty, but now it is working. I was getting an asynchronous  suspension error before, but I fixed it now. Maybe this has something to do with it. Anyway thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

Actually Google Cloud Storage does not have genuine "folders", this is why you get the "Object does not exist at location" exception.

In the Cloud Storage console, the files in your bucket are presented in a hierarchical tree of folders (just like the file system on your local hard disk) but this is just a way of presenting the files: there aren't genuine folders/directories in a bucket. The Cloud Storage console just uses the different parts of the file paths to "simulate" a folder structure, by using the "/" delimiter character.

This [doc](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/folders) on Cloud Storage and gsutil explains and illustrates very well this "illusion of a hierarchical file tree".